# core_url_rewrite doesn't get written during indexing

Tags: url-rewrite

Tired and extremely sleepy after 2 days of trying to find a solution, here I am on magento form requesting help and support.

Problem:

I truncated core_url_rewrite table and then tried to index. Though the indexing shows that it is writing to the table (phpMyAdmin shows the increment in size of table), when I actually browse the table, I do not find any data. It is clean and blank. I have checked the privileges and did the reindex from ssh using root login yet nothing seems to show up.

Already copied table structure from backup table but that doesn't seem to do the trick. All locks were removed from var/lock. Also reset the value in index_process from working to pending. Removed all cache files from var/cache.

Strangely, all other indexes work fine except catalog_url. :-(

Any help/suggestions is welcome as I am desperately looking for a solution to resolve this one.

Additional info: I am on a VPS and running 1.7 CE.

Comment: Just to be certain: `SELECT * FROM core_url_rewrite;` returns 0 results, yes?

Answer (score 2):

Found the reason. apparently the old php memory limit was the cause. Increased limit of php memory in .htaccess and tried again and it worked.